# How do I get rid of the Chapter title?

Tags: chapters

I am using document class {book} and I want to get rid of the chapter titles.  I don't want them to show up at the beginning of the chapter, but I do want the name of the chapter to still show up in the table of contents. I only want to get rid of select chapter titles, not all of them How to I do this?

Comment: That's a weird request. Could you provide us with a sample document showing your usage? For example, do you use `\chapter*`? If not, one could provide an interface where `\chapter` creates a regular, numbered chapter *with* the usual header, while `\chapter*` does the same *without* the header.

Comment: I am using \chapter{}, but I would like the chapter name to show up in the index, which is why I didn't use \chapter*.

Comment: So should `\chapter` *without* the header still start a new page (like it usually does?

Comment: \chapter doesn't, and keep in mind I do want the chapter name to show up in the table of contents.

Comment: If you're using `book` and `\chapter` *doesn't* start a new page, then you're doing something different than usual. Please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current behaviour. Then also specify what you want the input to look like for you "unmarked" chapters.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\addcontentsline` command.

> \addcontentsline{<*file line*>}{<*entry*>}{<*text>*}

The *file line* is **toc**, **lof**, or **lot**.

The *entry* is what level (chapter, section, etc).

And *text* is what you want the entry to say.

For you, it would be \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{*chapter title*}